# Where do I put code in Sinatra (ruby web framework) that I just want to execute once?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I don't know if this is a ruby question or a Sinatra question, because I'm new to both.  The following code does not work, and I understand why, because the first my_variable is local to its block.  I just don't know the syntax for getting it right.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

configure do
    my_variable = "world"
end

get '/' do
    "Hello " + my_variable
end
```

EDIT1 - the following works, but then I guess I'm confused about the proper purpose of the configure block.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

my_variable = "world"

get '/' do
    "Hello " + my_variable
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

set :my_variable, "world"

get '/' do
  "Hello " + settings.my_variable
end
```

Comment: I guess, I'm confused about the purpose of a Sinatra config block versus doing something outside of a block.

Comment: Options are application level settings while configuration allows you to customize the behavior according to current environment.

Comment: configure is just a block of code which will be executed once.

Answer (score 3):

Configure block is just to app configuration related. If that's what it is, you should encapsulate it proper:

```
require 'sinatra'

configure do
  set :my_option, "world"
end

get '/' do
  "Hello #{options.my_option}"
end
```

Comment: Fine, but it's not `options` anymore, it's `settings`.

Answer (score 0):

One other way is :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

@my_variable="world"

get '/' do
  "Hello " + @my_variable
end
```

Comment: I don't recommend using an instance variable because it isn't clear what object the instance variable affects.

Answer (score 0):

I would set a class variable — eg. `@@my_variable` — inside the configure block. The configure block exists for code you want to run at start up, so setting your variable their makes sense. Your Sinatra application is a subclass of `Sinatra::Base`, so using a class variable in this situation seems appropriate.